# How to move down UISearchController?

Tags: swift, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I’m using UISearchController with navigationItem.titleView:

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logoMain"))
```

The search field is sticking to the image in the navigation bar:

[image]

How to move it down for some points?

Comment: Can't you change the height of the frame of the `titleView`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there’s no any appropriate way to do this at the moment. You can try to increase the navbar height but it causes the visual issues when the search becomes active and slides into navbar.  I guess, the only way to do this is to make a navbar image height a bit smaller, so that the padding between the image and input becomes a bit larger. I used this solution.